# Is it bad to use screws on frozen wood?

Tags: woodworking

A plank of our wooden fence outside came off. Long story. Anyway it’s below freezing, and I’m wondering if it would be a problem for me to reattach this with screws while it’s so cold.

Comment: Besides frozen fingers should be okay, would drill pilot hole instead of just screwing in.

Answer (score 1):

No problem at all. Go for it. Just use something water resistant like GRK screws or stainless steel.